# "The getter 'body' isn't defined for the type 'Response<dynamic>". on Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

i'm having a problem to put a response json on a List.

When i try to transform the body data (where the data comes) i get the error:

```
The getter 'body' isn't defined for the type 'Response<dynamic>'.
Try importing the library that defines 'body', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'body'.dartundefined_getter
```

My code is:

```
     onPressed: () async {
                                    Response response;
                                    Dio dio = new Dio();
                                    String url =
                                        'http://192.168.15.5:8090/api/getOs';
                                    response = await dio.post(url, data: {
                                      "numeroos": _numeroOsController.text   
                                    });


                                    final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) //Here is the error
                                            as Map<String, dynamic>;
                                    final List<ProdutoOs> loadedProducts = [];
                                    extractedData.forEach((key, value) {
                                      loadedProducts.add(ProdutoOs(
                                          cod_produto: value['Codigo_Produto'],
                                          qtd: value['Qtde'],
                                          desc: value['Descricao'],
                                          numOs: value['Numero_da_OS'],
                                          codOs: value['CodOS']));
                              
                                      Navigator.pop(context, true);

                                  
                                    });
                                    
                                  }
```

So i'm trying to put the response.body in a List but i cant, what am i doing wrong?

I have also tried using response.data and dont get the same error, the app runs but i get:

```
E/flutter (11379): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the await keyword when you're parsing the url

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
List responseElements = jsonDecode(response.body);
responseElements.map((singleJsonObject) => {
   // do your parsing here
});
```

Comment: Yes, but also doesnt work, i put at the end of the post the error.

Comment: I edited my answer. Check if it is OK now.

Comment: Still gets "Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'"

Comment: Maybe your API returns JSON Array instead of single json object. If so try this:
  List jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
  jsonResponse.map((jsonObject) => // do something

Comment: Sorry for the spam, but I have added a new edit of my response.

Comment: Also you could check your response.statusCode, just to be sure that your response is 200 or 2xx and this is not an error response for example (4xx or 5xx).

Comment: The code is 200, i can even print the response using  " print(response.data);" but i cant get this data to a List to manipulate in the app.

Comment: And yes, the json comes inside a array

Comment: Didnt understand your new suggestion, how can i make the parse part?

Answer (score 0):

add await before parsing the url